# How to get the value of an hidden element without a trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a slider that dynamically displays forms one at a time and on each form I have an hidden element that has a value I would like to be able to retrieve (using it's class) each time the next form is displayed so I can use that element in an ajax call to alter something displayed on another part of the page according.

so..

Is it possible to get the value of an element when it is displayed without a trigger and call an ajax call without a trigger?

I know it's a bit of a long shot but jQuery never seems to surprise me so I thought I'd ask the question..

Comment: I'm a little confused about your question.  You're trying to make an ajax call whenever a form element is displayed?  When do you want the ajax call to happen?

Comment: When the slider displays the next form.  There isn't anything I can use from the slider to act as a trigger for the ajax

Comment: Will you put your code into a jsfiddle?

Comment: I am sure you can trigger this using the slider, there is something telling the slider to move from 1 form to another this same thing should trigger your call

Comment: tricky, it's 800 lines

Comment: I just wondered if there was anything that could monitor a change in a value that I could use to trigger ajx

Comment: @CodeBird the slider moves to the next form when a tab is clicked, I have tried adding a class to the tab (it's a href in a li) but it is ignored, probably because of the jquery function I used to created the slider

Comment: why don't you call the ajax function when the tab is clicked. call the ajax with the value you want

Comment: I tried but the js file for the slider is minised and impossible to work out what is happening where and it won't let me attach a second call on the tabs.

Comment: It's not the end of the world if there isn't something i can use, it was for a 'it would be nice' function rather than a necessity

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do it is with `setTimeout` with the information you have given.

```
setTimeout(
    function(){
        //check the value and if it is what you want, call the ajax function
    },1000);
```

The right approach would be to set an event listener on the slider.